# Como obter o nome de outra tabela quando os IDs correspondem?

Tags: php, mysql

Bem, eu sou iniciante em php (embora eu esteja tentando aprender), e no momento estou preso na minha última etapa finalizando um arquivo php.
Eu tenho uma tabela chamada "Team", onde existem colunas chamadas "ID" e "Name" e outra tabela chamada "RecordByOpponent", onde existe uma coluna chamada "OppID" que corresponde a ID da outra tabela.

Esse é o meu código que funciona normalmente

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `RecordByOpponent`  WHERE `TeamID` = " . $TeamID . " "; 

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr><td>" . $row["OppID"]. "</td><td>" . $row["TotalWins"] . "</td><td>" . $row["TotalLosses"] . "</td><td>" . $row["Points"] . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else { echo "0 results"; }
$conn->close();
?>
```

Enquanto meu código funciona e eu recebo o ID do procurado, preciso obter o nome do Time e não o ID. Os IDs nas duas tabelas correspondem.

Como pode ser resolvido? Não consigo entender, apesar de estar tentando ...

[image: foto das tabelas e da pagina php]

Comment: faça um `inner join`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se eu bem entendi você quer capturar os dados que também estão em outra tabela, você terá que usar algum JOIN pra unir as tabelas, sua query ficaria algo assim:

```
$sql = "
  SELECT * FROM `RecordByOpponent`
  INNER JOIN `Team` ON `Team`.`ID` = `RecordByOpponent`.`TeamID`
  WHERE `RecordByOpponent`.`TeamID` = " . $TeamID . "     
";
```

A ideia é unir a tabela **RecordByOpponent** à Tabela **Team**, através dos IDs, afinal essa é a sua relação entre as tabelas.
Já que você está aprendendo a técnica agora, sugiro estudar também sobre ALIAS no SQL, ficando mais simples a sua busca.

Então onde você exibe na tabela, basta substituir o campo ID pelo nome do time (Supondo que seja o nome da cidade)

```
echo "<tr><td>" . $row["CityName"]. "</td><td>" . $row["TotalWins"] . "</td><td>" . $row["TotalLosses"] . "</td><td>" . $row["Points"] . "</td></tr>";
```

Também é uma técnica, você não chamar tudo com * e sim selecionar manualmente as colunas que você precisa (Também utilizando alias pra evitar duplicidade). É uma boa prática pra você já ir aprendendo =]

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu uma boa clareada sua ajuda, funcionou perfeita mente. Já comecei a procurar sobre ALIAS e etc.. MUITO OBRIGADO!

Answer (score -3):

Tenta assim:

```
$sql = "SELECT Name.Team, *.RecordByOpponent FROM `RecordByOpponent`, `Team`  
    WHERE `TeamID` = " . $TeamID . " " AND `TeamID` = `ID`;
```

Comment: Não consegui fazer retornar, tá ficando em branco.